# OrientDB 2.1.9 crashes with OStorageException EOFException when running SQL script in console

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I've been using my SQL database initialization script for a while, but it seems that recently the database crashes in the middle of the execution and I don't know why, but here's some details:

- I am running OrientDB on Ubuntu 14 Trusty x64 (via Vagrant)
- It always seems to crash while the script attempts to create a UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX, but doesn't always crash at the same UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX instruction

The script creates a lot of vertices and edges, but for example, it will crash here (see line with UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX):

```
CREATE CLASS Channel EXTENDS V;
CREATE PROPERTY Channel.version LONG;
CREATE PROPERTY Channel.channelId STRING;
CREATE INDEX Channel.uq_channelId ON Channel(channelId) UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX;
```

The database crashes entirely with the following error:

> Creating index... Error:
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Error
>   on executing command: sql.create INDEX Channel.uq_channelId ON
>   Channel(channelId) UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX
>
> Error: java.io.EOFException

Looking at the log files, the only hint I get are the last two lines:

```
2016-01-14 17:17:05:437 INFO  Received signal: SIGTERM [OSignalHandler] 
2016-01-14 17:17:05:454 INFO  Received signal: SIGTERM [OSignalHandler]
```

How can I resolve this issue, or at least get better hints as to what is making the database crash?

I also test with OrientDB 2.1.6, as I was running the older version initially. Same problem.

Comment: Just tested 2.1.9 on a Mac, azul zulu jdk 1.8. I tested your 4 lines, no more. Did you create the index AFTER inserting data or on empty  db ? It's not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, false alarm -- this is a Vagrant issue, not an OrientDB issue. Running the exact same script on a 32bit instance instead of 64bit solved my problem, and installing the same script on a real 64bit server also works.

Comment: Additional note: if you encounter the same problem when running a large OrientDB SQL script on a Vagrant instance, it's likely because the virtual machine is running out of RAM. Try creating a swap file and trying again, worked for me.